# c++ operator overloading: NTL library export/import of a ZZ_pX vector

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream, ntl

I'm trying to  export and import a NTL vector from type ZZ_pX. After Reading the [source code](https://github.com/u-u-h/NTL/blob/master/src/ZZ_pX.c#L53) i found this interesting  operator functions:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& s, ZZ_pX& x)
{
   NTL_INPUT_CHECK_RET(s, s >> x.rep);
   x.normalize();
   return s;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const ZZ_pX& a)
{
   return s << a.rep;
}
```

then i wrote this code for exporting :

```
    ZZ_pX phi;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("phi.txt");
    myfile <<  phi;
    myfile.close();
```

and for the importing i tried to do something like this :

```
   ZZ_pX phi;
   std::ifstream dataFile("phi.txt");
   while (!dataFile.fail() && !dataFile.eof() )
   {
       dataFile >> phi ;
       cout << phi;
   }
```

The exporting is working but not the importing, error:

```
ZZ_p constructor called while modulus undefined
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Sorry if this is very simple as I quite new to C++

Comment: This has nothing to do with operator overloading. You need to read the documentation of the software you are using and understand how it works. Control question: what does `p` in `ZZ_pX` stand for?

Comment: The class ZZ_pX implements polynomial arithmetic modulo p.

Comment: Right, and what is p?

Comment: p in this case is a  single-precision prime

Comment: Yeah. *Which* prime? 2? 13? 101?

Comment: (1<<30) -> 1073741824

Comment: First this number is not a prime, second, where dies it come from? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I found in the NTL documentation that class ZZ_p represents the
integers mod p. Despite the notation, p need NOT in general be prime, except in situations where this is mathematically required.  In my case I p is equal to 512.

Comment: here is the solution for the problem :

#define N0 512
.
.
.
.
    int i=0;
    SetCoeff(phi,N0);
    while(dataFile>>buf){ // write each number in buffer
        phi[i]=atoi(buf);
        i++;       
   }
    cout << phi;

thanks for your help ! :)